# How to relate the Category to user?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, users, wpdb, user-meta

I am developing one new  plugin, In that i had a section to create new category, and having the field Created By(listing all the users in this field).

I am storing the category name in WP_terms and the user name in the WP_usermeta. And now i need to display the Category list by corresponding users created, how can i make this please give me an idea.

Comment: I have get this job done by creating one new table, And store the Category id and the Usermeta value each and every time the category is  created, And now i just listed the category with the Created By value in the frontend.

Comment: Hi, Elan, you can answer your own Question bellow. This way, the Q doesn't remain "unanswered" and normally folks won't look at the comments for the solution, but at the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

The job was done by creating one new table. And storing the Category ID and the User Meta value each and every time the category is created.

Now, just list the category with the `Created By` value in the frontend.

<sub>*Answer pulled from an OP comment.*</sub>